# Set value of a specific field in a formBuilder with setData()?

Tags: php, api, field, symfony, formbuilder

i'm actually working on an api created with symfony. 
I'v got a specific need to create a ressource with a post request. i'v got to update my updated_at field to make an upload of file with vichuploaderBundle. Everything is working well, but now i would like to use my form to create a Post with a post request.

Here is how i was doing it before in my PostController.

```
 public function postPostsAction(Request $request)
 {
     $post = new Post();
     $post->setTitle($request->get('title'))
         ->setDescription($request->get('description'))
         ->setImageName($request->get('image_name'))
         ->setImageFile($request->files->get('imageFile'))
         // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
         // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
         ->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());


     // On fait appel à doctrine pour seter un id lors de la création en base
     $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
     $em->persist($post);
     $em->flush();

     return $post;
 }
```

Here is now how i do to use my form

```
 public function postPostsAction(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
    $form->submit($request->request->all()); // Validation des données
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();
        return $post;
    } else {
        return $form;
    }
}
```

here is my form

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('title')->add('description')->add('imageName')->add('imageFile', FileType::class)
            ->add('updated_at');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Post',
        //An API must be stateless, Cross-Site Request Forgery must be disable
        'csrf_protection' => false,
        'allow_extra_fields' => true,
    ));
}
```

I want to set the updated_at with something like \new dateTime() to make my user not specify himself an updated_at.  I saw that it's possible with setData() but don't know how to do it to a specific field in the builder and not all the builder himself.  Thx for helping and feedbacks on my Question !

here is my postman if it can help [image: postman post request]

Comment: `if ($form->isValid()) { $post->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime()); ...`

Comment: I tried this before, no error is returned, but my pictures aren't saved anymore in the specified directory ( i'm using vichuploader to upload files), the fact is that, my first part of code is working good, but not with the form.

Comment: Because your add `updated_add` field into the form in `formBuilder` method. Now the form is not valid if the field is empty. Remove that field from the form.

Comment: well even without the field, the files aren't saved in the directory, any error are returned......i'm pretty lost